# How can I get current date and time in my format with GMT in Go?

Tags: datetime, go

I'm trying to get date and time like this 2014-06-22 22:00:22 GMT+2
What is the best way to do it?

I'm trying various variants. The closest was this

```
time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05 GMT+1")
```

And I get good result, except the GMT - it's wrong. I'v triyed to change the template like this and got results:

> GMT+0 => GMT+0
>
> GMT+1 => GMT+4

But I live in GMT+3 and expect that number.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

For example, for Moscow, GMT+03,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    // Your Local time zone
    now := time.Now().Round(0)
    fmt.Println(now.UTC())
    fmt.Println(now)
    t := now.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05 GMT-07")
    fmt.Println(t)

    // For example, use Moscow time zone (GMT+03)
    fmt.Println()
    moscow, err := time.LoadLocation("Europe/Moscow")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    now = time.Now().In(moscow)
    fmt.Println(now.UTC())
    fmt.Println(now)
    t = now.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05 GMT-07")
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

Output:

```
2019-04-19 17:24:20.582630875 +0000 UTC
2019-04-19 13:24:20.582630875 -0400 EDT
2019-04-19 13:24:20 GMT-04

2019-04-19 17:24:20.582729015 +0000 UTC
2019-04-19 20:24:20.582729015 +0300 MSK
2019-04-19 20:24:20 GMT+03
```

Answer (score -2):

[Per the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants) the `time` package supports `hhmm`, `hh:mm`, and `hh` formats; single-digit `h` offset is not directly supported:

> Numeric time zone offsets format as follows:

```
-0700  ±hhmm
-07:00 ±hh:mm
-07    ±hh
```

Remember that the format string for `time.Format` is telling it *how to render the parts of Time*. It does not *change* anything about the `Time`, *including its locale*. If you want to render a time in a different time zone, use [`Time.In`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.In) to get the time in a different time zone:

```
timeInGMTPlus3 := time.Now().In(time.FixedZone("some zone", int((3 * time.Hour).Seconds()))
```

Comment: Ok, I'm trying ±hh: `fmt.Println(time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05 GMT+03"))` and getting result `2019-04-19 19:35:27 GMT+07`, but I still need GMT+03

Comment: That should work fine, but you have to use the correct offset for format strings (+0700). Check the docs.

Comment: I think I understand where you're having trouble - see updated answer.

Comment: Oh, I understood my mistake. I should literally write GMT-07 to get my current local offset GMT+03

Comment: Yes, the format string must represent the exact date/time/locale specified in the docs.